# Select columns which have more the 2 values in other column

Tags: mysql

I have a table which have 3 columns and we need to select data of those rows which have multiple entry in the table.

```
 Column1  Colum2    Colum3
 ---------------------------
 ARRG   | MEM      | 10.12
 ARRG   | MHH      | 0.245
 ARRG   | MHH      | 0.246
 ABC    | HQ       | 0.246
 CDE    | PRT      | 97.0
 TST    | TRY      | 97.0
```

Now I want to write a query to select rows from `Column1` which have unique values in `Colum2`
Basically i want to print the rows of ARRG as this have 2 different values in `Colum2`.

```
ARRG   | MEM      | 10.12
ARRG   | MHH      | 0.245
```

Comment: So from your example output, you want the First row from the ARRG,MHH set. Is that correct

Comment: Why `ABC    | HQ       | 0.246` is not unique ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes that's right

Comment: @ErgestBasha I want to select only those which have more than 1 rows in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select Column1,Colum2,Colum3
from test 
where Column1 in (select Column1
                  from test
                  group by Column1
                  having count(distinct Colum2)>1
                 )
group by Column1,Colum2,Colum3;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0e12a9ed7905c2d38f5de89fee330b4)